# Can you configure eclipse to code assist some imports rather than others

Tags: eclipse, content-assist, import

Eclipse sometimes automatically inserts imports into my java code, but it often gets them wrong.  Are there ways to configure the guesses that it makes.  I would like to tell it to always import java.util.List rather than java.awt.list for example.  There are also a bunch of others that it gets wrong including Pattern, Matcher, Logger, Node,  and Element.  All of which I have a preferred class that I use all the time but there are many other classes with the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure certain imports to be hidden from the content assist dialog via Window | Preferences | Java | Appearance | Type Filters.

For example, adding a filter such as `java.awt.*` would hide all types from the `awt` packages.

However this is probably only useful if you don't use those classes at all, as it won't show any content assist information for them. I haven't come across a way to prefer certain packages or class names over others.

Under Window | Preferences | Java | Editor | Content Assist | Favorites there are some options for adding types and members, but I think these only apply to static members.

Comment: Had a problem that objects in My own packages are hidden. Found that some how it was set to filtered in _Window | Preferences | Java | Appearance | Type Filters._